# Get first Monday after third Friday

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get all the `rows` of the first Monday after the third Friday of the month.

This doesn't work:

```
select DATEADD(DAY, 3, ThirdFriday) AS first_monday_after_third_friday_of_month
From
select quote_date
FROM ([Underlying].[dbo].[Table]
 where  datename(weekday, quote_date) = 'Friday'
and datepart(day, quote_date)>=15 and datepart(day, quote_date)<=21)
AS ThirdFriday
```

Comment: Please some some sample data and desired results (as formatted text).

Comment: Why have you re-posted the same question from [dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-server)?

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Can you be a little more vague than a [Help Vampire's](https://web.archive.org/web/20180216144029/https://www.skidmore.edu/~pdwyer/e/eoc/help_vampire.htm) "This doesn't work"?

Comment: See the example given below by John Cappelletti. That is basically what I need, except he does it for a hardwired date. I need to select all the rows that match those Mondays in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a calendar table it would be easier, but here we use an ad-hoc tally table to create an ad-hoc calendar table.

**Example**

```
Declare @Date1 date = '2021-08-01'

Select top 1 with ties 
       ThirdFriday = D
      ,NextMonday  = dateadd(DAY,3,D)
 From ( Select Top 31 D=DateAdd(DAY,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),@Date1) 
         From  master..spt_values n1
      ) A
 Where DateName(WEEKDAY,D)='Friday'
 Order By case when row_number() over (order by d) = 3 then 0 else 1 end
```

**Results**

```
ThirdFriday NextMonday
2021-08-20  2021-08-23
```

**Update**

By increasing the scope (i.e. 15000 days) and adding a partition by year and month.

The results can be JOINED to your table

**Example**

```
Declare @Date1 date = '2000-01-01'

Select top 1 with ties 
       ThirdFriday = D
      ,NextMonday  = dateadd(DAY,3,D)
 From ( Select Top 15000 D=DateAdd(DAY,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),@Date1) 
         From  master..spt_values n1,master..spt_values n2
      ) A
 Where DateName(WEEKDAY,D)='Friday'
 Order By case when row_number() over (partition by year(D),month(D) order by d) = 3 then 0 else 1 end
```

**Results**

```
ThirdFriday NextMonday
2000-01-21  2000-01-24
2000-02-18  2000-02-21
2000-03-17  2000-03-20
...
2040-11-16  2040-11-19
2040-12-21  2040-12-24
2041-01-18  2041-01-21
```

Comment: John thanks I tried that and it works for your date. How do I modify it so that it picks out all the rows in the table that match the First Monday after third Friday?

Comment: @Ivan  Regardless of Month and Year ?